How to get metaobject data using the shopify admin graphql api
I am creating a student portal for the students who pay for a monthly subscription through shopify as a react vite app. I have metaobjects for lessons, assignments and assessments, whose information will be shown in a calendar in the portal using react big calendar. I was able to get data about my products using the admin rest api and it was shown in json format at http://localhost:5000/api/products. However, when I tried to do the same using graphql this time, it gave me this error in the terminal:
Error response from Shopify: {"errors":"Not Found"}
Error fetching metaobjects: Error: Network response was not ok
    at file:///.../backend/server.js:78:10
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)

I am new to graphql so debugging this issue has been very difficult and I haven't been able to find a solution after tweaking the code multiple times.
I have a .env file in the same directory which stores the SHOPIFY_STORE_URL and SHOPIFY_API_ACCESS_TOKEN.
How do I fix this?
server.js
import express from "express";
import cors from "cors";
import fetch from "node-fetch";
import dotenv from "dotenv";

dotenv.config();

const app = express();
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000;

app.use(cors());
app.use(express.json()); // For parsing application/json

// REST API route for products
app.get("/api/products", async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const response = await fetch(
            `https://${process.env.SHOPIFY_STORE_URL}/admin/api/2024-07/products.json`,
            {
                method: "GET",
                headers: {
                    "Content-Type": "application/json",
                    "X-Shopify-Access-Token":
                        process.env.SHOPIFY_API_ACCESS_TOKEN,
                },
            },
        );

        if (!response.ok) {
            const errorText = await response.text();
            console.error("Error response from Shopify:", errorText);
            throw new Error("Network response was not ok");
        }

        const data = await response.json();
        res.json(data.products);
    } catch (error) {
        console.error("Error fetching products:", error);
        res.status(500).send("Error fetching products");
    }
});

// GraphQL API route for metaobjects (using POST)
app.get("/api/metaobjects", async (req, res) => {
    const query = `
    {
  metaobjects(type: "lessons", first: 10) {
    edges {
      node {
        id
        fields {
          key
          value
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
  `;

    try {
        const response = await fetch(
            `https://${process.env.SHOPIFY_STORE_URL}/admin/api/2024-07/graphql.json`,
            {
                method: "POST",
                headers: {
                    "Content-Type": "application/json",
                    "X-Shopify-Access-Token":
                        process.env.SHOPIFY_API_ACCESS_TOKEN,
                },
                body: JSON.stringify({ query }),
            },
        );

        if (!response.ok) {
            const errorText = await response.text();
            console.error("Error response from Shopify:", errorText);
            throw new Error("Network response was not ok");
        }

        const data = await response.json();
        if (data.errors) {
      console.error("GraphQL errors:", data.errors);
      throw new Error('GraphQL errors');
    }
  
    return data.data.metaobjects.edges.map(edge => edge.node);
    } catch (error) {
        console.error("Error fetching metaobjects:", error);
        res.status(500).send("Error fetching metaobjects");
    }
});

app.listen(PORT, () => {
    console.log(`Server is running on port ${PORT}`);
});

